# Woocommerce adding image to product gallery fails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am doing Wordpress Woocommerce plugin that needs to download and add image to Product Image and same image also to Product Gallery.

Adding image to Product Image works but it adding to Product Gallery does not. Manually adding same image to gallery on product edit page makes gallery visible.

What is missing so that Product Gallery image is not added?

Code used to do that is:

```
    $uploaded_image_path = $uploads['path'] . "/tyreimage_$imageId.jpg";
    copy("http://tyreimagesource/images/tyres/$imageId.jpg", $uploaded_image_path);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($uploaded_image_path, null);
    $attachment  = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title'     => $imageId . ".jpg",
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $uploaded_image_path, $productId);
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $uploaded_image_path);
    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_data);
    set_post_thumbnail($productId, $attach_id);
    add_post_meta($productId, '_product_image_gallery', $attach_id);
```

After running this code I am seeing

[image: View after adding gallery]

After adding same image manually I see

[image]

Comment: May be try checking records in database, does it get inserted ?

Comment: It apprears in DB. I even enabled DB logging and these are getting executed: 
2018-02-23T08:44:39.103050Z   255 Query INSERT INTO `wp_tables_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (19023, '_thumbnail_id', '19042')
2018-02-23T08:44:39.105449Z   255 Query INSERT INTO `wp_tables_postmeta` (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (19023, '_product_image_gallery', '19042')

Comment: And how does the db record looks like when you upload it manually. And also try db logging if it inserting any record to somewhere else. Then try comparing the db records from manual upload and programmitally one. (Sorry if not being helpful :S )

Comment: Can you show all your code including the part where you upload the image?  Otherwise just check this guide and you can see where you are going wrong. https://ryanknights.co.uk/insert-product-variation-gallery-images-programatically-into-woocommerce/

Comment: Updated to full image attachment code